# Foreign Fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am currently working on a Django project. 
 I am using Foreign Fields in one of the models.

```
class Purchase (models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True, null = True)
       game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
       ...
```

And accessing these values in views like

```
p = Purchase.objects.filter(user=request.user,game=request.POST['gameid'])
```

In DB(i am using Postgres), the fields in Purchase Table are user_id and game_id
respectively for user and game.
I think its the Django default to suffix foreign fields with _id.

So i tried a bit in manage.py shell
and i came to know that i am getting same amount of results even if i use

```
 p = Purchase.objects.filter(user_id=request.user,game_id=request.POST['gameid'])
```

So my doubt is that whether the field names defined in model and exact names of those fields in DB can be used interchangeably? Any further information or explanation would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does this for foreign key fields. If you want to have the same name in the database then you can define column name using [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='user')
```

P.S you can use both `user_id` and `user` to reference foreign key. This is absolutely fine. But i will suggest you to use model level names to avoid confusions.